# How can I filter only a particular data from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I just need to extract a specific data from this. For eg: mobile no:

This is just a result from the console:
[image: Result from the console].

What code should I write on my JS.

Answer (score 0):

If its an object, you can just access its properties by calling its name after the dot (eg `myObject.mobile`) or by bracket syntax: `myObject['mobile']`

All you need to know: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

If it's a collection, just use `forEach` or `map` function (or any other available method) to iterate over it and then access property as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [LoDash](https://lodash.com/). Add the library to your project and use .pick method. If your data is an Array, then use .map method

```
var data = {
var1: 1,
var2: 2,
var3: 3
};

console.log(data);
var mappedData = _.pick(data,  'var2' );
console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is an object,

```
var data = { entryId: 'ABC', mobile: '0123456789' } 
console.log(data.entryId)  // 'ABC'
console.log(data.mobile)  // '0123456789'
```

If your data is an array of objects,

```
var data = [
          { entryId: 'ABC', mobile: '0123456789' }, 
          { entryId: 'BBB', mobile: '1111111111' },
          { entryId: 'CCC', mobile: '2222222222' }
];

var dataWithMobileNumbersOnly = data.map((obj) => {
   return { mobile: obj.mobile };
}); 

console.log(dataWithMobileNumbersOnly) // [{mobile: '0123456789'}, {mobile: '1111111111'}, {mobile: '2222222222'}]
```

For more information about map() method, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map